# Looping over dictionary recursively and remove keys

Tags: haskell, dictionary, recursion

I'm using vertices and a `Data.Map` to try and make capture moves for the game of Checkers. I'm using a function `changeKey` to update a current key in the map and a function `cMove` to make the capture moves. Right now, `cMove` takes a vertex, a list of vertices (with the opponents pieces) and a map containing vertices and a bool value to indicate which player the piece belongs to. `cMove` checks if the first vertex tuple is in the map (to know if the position on the board is empty or not, as the calculation finds a position of a valid move). If it is, `changeKey` will be called.

```
changeKey :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool
changeKey k0 k1 myMap = case M.updateLookupWithKey (\_ _ -> Nothing) k0 myMap of
         (Nothing, _    ) -> myMap
         (Just e, myMap) -> M.insert k1 e myMap

cMove :: (Integer, Integer) -> [(Integer, Integer)] -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool
cMove k [k1] myMap = if M.notMember (2*fst k1 - fst k, 2*snd k1 - snd k) myMap
                          then
                          changeKey k (2*fst k1 - fst k, 2*snd k1 - snd k) myMap
                          else myMap
```

My problem here lies in the fact that I'm in the dark with how I can loop through the list of vertices, if the list contains more than one tuple (as a player can do unlimited amount of captures per turn). Furthermore, how can I make sure each of the keys representing the opponent's pieces will be deleted from the map.

Comment: You shouldn't use function calls that look like this: `fst(k1)`. You should instead use just `fst k1`, like `2*fst k1 - fst k`.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Judging by the spelling of its name, `ChangeKey` can't be a function.

Comment: Edited to fix `changeKey` capitalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that [the documentation for `Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map.html) recommends that you use `Data.Map.Strict` instead of `Data.Map` in circumstances like you have.

Also, function names should generally start with a lower-case letter.

---

With that out of the way, a simple way to do iteration here is to [fold the elements of a list](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold) into a final result `Map`. You write a function to deal with one iteration (see `cMove'` below), then you use something like `foldr` or `foldl'` to have it do all the iterations for you.

I'm not sure if the following gives you the behavior you want, but here's a first draft using `foldr`:

```hs
import Data.Map.Strict (Map(..))
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

changeKey :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool
changeKey k0 k1 myMap = case M.updateLookupWithKey (\_ _ -> Nothing) k0 myMap of
         (Nothing, _    ) -> myMap
         (Just e, myMap) -> M.insert k1 e myMap

cMove :: (Integer, Integer) -> [(Integer, Integer)] -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool
cMove k ks myMap = foldr (cMove' k) myMap ks
  where
    cMove' :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool -> Map (Integer, Integer) Bool
    cMove' k k1 myMap = if M.notMember (2*fst k1 - fst k, 2*snd k1 - snd k) myMap
                              then changeKey k (2*fst k1 - fst k, 2*snd k1 - snd k) myMap
                              else myMap
```

Comment: It is getting there. One problem is, that the new k is not being used for the rest of the list, but the old one is. To clarify, whenever changeKey gets called, cMove is supposed to use the new vertex k instead of the original one.

Comment: So if the list is `[a, b, c, d, e]`, it should use `k` and `a` the first time, `a` and `b` the second time, `b` and `c` the third time, and so on?